# Is it possible to write transactional unit tests that test transactional code?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, transactions, aop

I am writing an application using Spring.  I want to write my JDBC code to be transactional, which I can achieve by using AOP:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" rollback-for="MyCustomException"/>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="MyCustomException" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="pc" expression="execution(* com.me.jdbc.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="pc" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="simpleDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:aas;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=true" />
</bean>
```

So all my methods in com.me.jdbc should be transactional and rollback if a MyCustomException occurs.  This works so far.

I now want to write a unit test, but I want my unit test to be transactional, such that, once the test is complete the entire transaction will roll back and leave the database the way it was at the start.

I am able to achieve this by declaring:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@Transactional
```

on my Test class.  The problem however is that I lose the transactions on the application code, i.e. after each test the transactions are rolled back, but if an exception occurs in the application code the insert is not rolled back and my unit test fails because I expect the table to be empty, but it isn't.

How would I go about achieving these two levels of transaction?  Is it possible?  I can work around the problem by writing a setup method for my unit tests that clears out all of the tables before each test.  I am fine with this, but I thought it would be good to be able to use the rollback method of achieving the same thing.

Comment: I suspect that the reason it doesn't work is that as soon as I make my unit test transactional, the transaction wraps the whole test and the rollback will only occur if the test throws the exception (or ends), but since I am catching the exception so that I can assert that the database is still empty, the rollback doesn't occur until the method ends. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Is there any reference telling that transaction will roll back when exception other than MyException occurs?

Comment: Your analysis is correct. You should simply test that an exception is thrown. That's sufficient to make your test pass, since you know that such an exception will cause the transaction to rollback. The goal of the test is not to check that the Spring configuration works fine. The goal is to test that your code does what it should do. If you want to test that the Spring configuration works fine, then your test shouldn't be transactional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments section, the issue is that by making the test method encapsulate a transaction, the rollback will only occur if the test throws the exception.  This makes it impossible to verify the behaviour under test before the exception is thrown.  I have gone with the approach of just emptying all the tables in the setup method (before each test).